# Error connecting to a postgres db with nodejs sequelize pg.js "the dialect postgres is not supported"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to establish a simple connection from a NodeJs app to my Postgres local database.
Here is the content of my node code index2.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var PGPASS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, "./.pgpass");

var pgtokens = fs.readFileSync(PGPASS_FILE).toString().trimRight().split(":");
var host = pgtokens[2];
var port = pgtokens[3];
var dbname = pgtokens[4];
var user = pgtokens[0];
var password = pgtokens[1];

var conString = "postgres://"+user+":"+password+"@"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname;

var pg = require('pg.js');
var Sequelize =  require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbname, user, password,{
      dialectModulePath:"pg.js",
      dialect: "postgres",
      port: 5432
    });

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .complete(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the database', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection has been establised succesfully!');
    }
  })
```

I am using the module `pg.js` not `pg` to connect to Postgres and I have tested that it works.

My problem is with Sequelize. The error I get is the following:

```
c:\psql-node\node-modules\sequelize\lib\transaction-manager.js:10
throw new Error("The dialect + sequelize.getDialect()+"  is not support
       ^
Error: The dialect postgres is not suppported.
    at new module.exports (c:\psql-node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\transaction-manager.js:10:11)
    at new module.exports.Sequelize (c:\psql-node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:128:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\psql-node\index2.js:16:17)
etc...
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if how I tell Sequelize to use `'pg.js'` is correct, that's the line `dialectModulePath:"pg.js"`
Any ideas?

Edit:
Thanks to @peter-lyons I found out a bit more about the issue:
The error I get is almost the same but before it indicates:

```
[Error: Cannot find module 'pg/lib/connection-parameters'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

which is normal as the path to it should be `pg.js/lib/connection-parameters`
Any idea how I modify `node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js` so it gets the right file?

Comment: OK, so now to be sane, be sure you are using the absolute most recent version of sequelize. The code in master looks like it should work OK. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4c1e14b56627689e5862e675b96cac8352a2359f/lib/dialects/postgres/connector-manager.js#L22

Comment: I downloaded it yesterday, with npm install --save sequelize and it added in my package.json the '^1.7.3' version. However I checked your link and my connector-managers.js file and this particular line is missing, so will try to uninstall and reinstall to see if this makes a difference, otherwise will modify it by hand and report an issue on Sequelize's github. Thx @PeterLyons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in theory your snippet should work, but the sequelize code is throwing an error that I suspect is misleading. You'll need to edit the `lib/transaction-manager.js` file because it is swallowing the error details you need. Add a `console.error(err)` in the `catch` block before the `throw` to make sure that error is not something else weird like your install of sequelize is missing files or not dealing with windows paths correctly or something like that. Make that one change, rerun your snippet, and update your question with the details if that doesn't lead you to a root cause and a solution directly.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get exactly the same error. And how would Sequelize know that it needs to use pg.js instead of the pg module if I don't indicate this option?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but what I indicate as option is mentionned here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Sequelize#Sequelize I'm not inventing it, maybe I don't know how to use it, that's for sure!

Comment: Ah, so sequelize seems to be swallowing the error that might explain WTF is really the problem. Answer updated again.

Comment: Edited as requested. Thx for your help.